# iOS App Crashes with newer IB Classes - Weird

Tags: ios

I have an app that I originally developed for iOS 3 back in March 2009.  I've been constantly updating it for the past two and a half years.  I've maintained a deployment target of 3.1.3 ever since early on.

I recently decided to upgrade to OSX Lion and XCode 4.2.  I opened my app in the 4.3 iOS Simulator and tried out the latest feature I had added.  I have a background button that does a resignFirstResponder on all UITextFields in the view.  I put the cursor in the UITextField that was recently added to this view that's been around since the beginning.  When I hit the background button, the app crashed.  I tried again but used a textfield that's been around since the beginning, that background button didn't crash the app.  I tested on all UITextFields that have been added in the past few months and it crashes on all of them, it doesn't crash on any old UITextFields.  I went to other places in the app too, like a search bar that was added just a few days ago, whenever I focus the textfield and hit a key, app crash.  On an older search bar in another view, no crash.

Think of it like this, any IB Class that was added in the past few months doesn't work.  **BUT  if I delete the broken UITextField, copy/paste an old/original UITextField and rewire that to the IBOutlets, it works!**

To top it all off, everything works fine in the iOS 5 simulator.

**UPDATE - Problem Solved**

While typing all this, I went into XCode Properties and saw there was an update to the 4.3 Simulator in the Downloads tab.  Installed that and everything is working now.  Frustrating.

Comment: Even though it sounds like a strange thing to do, the usual practice around here when you solve your own problem is to add an answer and mark it as accepted. That helps people see that the question has been answered.

Comment: Hi Caleb,  I tried to do that immediately but I don't have enough reputation so I had to wait 9 hours.  I can't mark it as accepted for two days but I will return to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by updating the iOS Simulator from Xcode Preferences, the downloads tab.